# get ssis package output from SP

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a SP that runs a SSIS package.

```
xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /f "F:\SSIS Package\test.dtsx" /Rep E'
```

When I run the SP in VS I get an Output window where I can see if it was successful.
Is there a way to get the output from this into my asp.net application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One practice I've often seen is to capture the results into a table. Something along these lines:

```
create table #dtexecOutput(varchar(4000))

insert into #dtexecOutput exec master..xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /f "F:\SSIS Package\test.dtsx" /Rep E' 

select * from  #dtexecOutput
```

Comment: Yes this is what I've done too.Although this kinda looks like a hack to me. But it gets the job done :).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be an output redirect to a file and then reading from the file:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /f "F:\SSIS Package\test.dtsx" /Rep E > output.log'
```

The name of the file should be dynamic and random enough.